# Char sent via socket

Tags: c, network-programming

This question is pure teoretical, and not about the right way of doing it, but do we need to convert char 'x' to network format? I'm intressted in all cases: always / sometimes / never 
I personally think I should but i need to be sure, than you.

Comment: *Which* "network format"? If it's *network byte order*,.. than see the answer by @G_G.

Comment: We're talking about two different things here. I believe *network byte order* refers to a form of octet order (specifically 8-bit bytes), while a byte in C has CHAR_BIT bits which may be greater than or equal to 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, char is a single byte value so endianess doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

As you're thinking of it (endianess, ntohs ntohl, etc...), no.

Less basically, I should raise a non-network-bound warning : Any string not attached with its encoding is unreadable.

Say you're sending/storing, over network or not, the string "Français" the 'ç' will have to be encoded using a character encoding. Not specifying the character encoding mean it can be read "FranÃ§ais" if you encoded it using utf8 but your reader was thinking it was latin1.

So you have two solutions :

- Write down a spec for you application to only use the same char encoding
- Put a metadata on a header somewhere specifying the encoding for future strings (like HTTP).

Comment: yes, more generally any *data* not attached with its encoding is unreadable. That's a basic rule which transcends networking or even computer science. Both ends need to share the same encoding/decoding rules or communication can't take place.